# flex 3's datagrid won't stretch

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I wrote very simple code to understand how columnstretch and calllater work but I couldn't get resizeGrid function worked. What is going on here?

```
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

        [Bindable]
        public var denemelist:ArrayCollection;


        private function calculateHeight(l:int):Number{
            return deneme.measureHeightOfItems(0, l) + deneme.headerHeight;             
        }

        public function resizeGrid():void{
        if(denemelist && deneme)
            deneme.height = calculateHeight(denemelist.length);
        }

        public function preinit():void {
            denemelist = new ArrayCollection([
            {former:"sdfad", latter:"sdfgs"},
            {former:"sdfgsd", latter:"sdfgsfd"}     
            ]);  
        }

        public function test():void {
        denemelist.addItem({former:"sdfgsdf", latter:"sdfgdsgf"});
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:VBox width="100%" height="500">
<mx:DataGrid  
    width="100%"
    resizeEffect="Resize"
    horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off"
    id="deneme"
    variableRowHeight="true" 
    editable="false"
    dataProvider="{denemelist}"
    styleName="phrDataGrid"
    columnStretch="callLater(resizeGrid)">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="former" headerText="former"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="latter" headerText="latter"/>
        </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>

<mx:Button label="deneme1" click="test()" />
</mx:VBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the datagrid has been updated yet at the time that you're calling the function.  But you might try leaving off the height of the dg and then just setting the rowCount to the number of items in the list.

HTH;
Amy

Comment: Your advice worked, thank you. However, it still does not explain why resizeGrid() function is not called at all ?

Comment: Are you dragging around the separator between the columns?  I think that's what you'd have to do to fire the event you put your resizeGrid handler on.

Comment: yeah, you are right. I forgot to call function externally. I thought it detects the length changes of the array collection. In this aspect, your way is more appropriate.